# Powershell getting chassis types info

Tags: powershell

I'm currently working on a powershell script that should retrieve the type of machine i'm working on and i've looked at several examples already but i can't get it to work properly. I want to retrieve my chassis type so i can determine if i'm working on a laptop or desktop.

This is my code:

```
$isLaptop = [bool](Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_SystemEnclosure -Property 
ChassisTypes | Where-Object ChassisTypes -in '{9}', '{10}', '{14}')
```

The problem is that even when i'm running the script on a desktop i'm getting a response which is true although the chassis type of my desktop is {3}.

I'm probably overlooking something stupid but would be nice if someone could give me some assistance here i'm kinda new to powershell aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is meant to be an alternative to Mark's answer for readability:

```
#requires -Version 3

$isLaptop = [bool](Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_SystemEnclosure |
    Where-Object ChassisTypes -in '{9}', '{10}', '{14}')
```

---

After trying to reproduce your problem, however, you're not working with the right types.  While the output of the command looks like this:

```
ChassisTypes : {3}
```

what you actually have is an array of `UInt16` there.  So what you need to compare to is one collection to another:

```
[uint16[]]$laptop = 9, 10, 14

$isLaptop = foreach ($chassis in (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_SystemEnclosure).ChassisTypes) {
    if ($chassis -in $laptop) {
        $true
        break
    }
}
```

And broken down a little further:

```
#requires -Version 4

$isLaptop = [bool](Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_SystemEnclosure).
    ChassisTypes.
    Where({ $PSItem -in 9, 10, 14 })
```

Comment: Nevermind looks like something is still wrong, If i just write-host $isLaptop i get the proper return but when i'm trying to actually implement it like this:

if($isLaptop = $true) { write-host Laptop}
else { write-host Desktop }

It always produces laptop

Comment: That's because `$isLaptop = $true` is *always* returning true.  Give me a second to link you to another post of mine

Comment: [Do read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51524013/win10-powershell-simple-if-elseif-depends-on-condition-order/51524115#51524115) @claeys

Comment: Yeah i'm sorry i'm not really used to powershell yet i just started using it to make some scripts on my internship

Comment: When you're dealing with boolean variables, you shouldn't compare them to a constant like `True`/`False`; they either are or aren't.  In this case, `if ($isLaptop) { ...` or `if (-not $isLaptop) { ...` @claeys

Comment: Thank you very much i understand and it's working now!

Comment: Glad to help.  I do recommend reading my other post about your `if` statement conundrum for understanding.  @claeys

Comment: For future reference, in *most* languages, `=` is *only* used for *assignment* to a variable, not comparison.  If my problem solved your question, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ChassisType = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_SystemEnclosure).ChassisTypes

if ($ChassisType -eq 9 -or $ChassisType -eq 10 -or $ChassisType -eq 14) {
    $isLaptop = $true
}
else {
    $isLaptop = $false
}

$isLaptop
```

Comment: Thanks i forgot that but still getting a true value when i'm expecting a false value since i'm working on a desktop atm

Answer (score 0):

This code is [taken from here](https://powershell.one/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_systemenclosure#chassistypes) and made into a function. It creates a hash table and translates the values to a human-readable form.

I've tested this in 5.1 and 7.1 and works for both of those. So it's future proof for a while yet.

```
Function Get-ChassisType() {

  $ChassisTypes = @{
    Name = 'ChassisType'
    Expression = {
      # property is an array, so process all values
      $result = foreach($value in $_.ChassisTypes)
      {
        switch([int]$value)
        {
          1          {'Other'}
          2          {'Unknown'}
          3          {'Desktop'}
          4          {'Low Profile Desktop'}
          5          {'Pizza Box'}
          6          {'Mini Tower'}
          7          {'Tower'}
          8          {'Portable'}
          9          {'Laptop'}
          10         {'Notebook'}
          11         {'Hand Held'}
          12         {'Docking Station'}
          13         {'All in One'}
          14         {'Sub Notebook'}
          15         {'Space-Saving'}
          16         {'Lunch Box'}
          17         {'Main System Chassis'}
          18         {'Expansion Chassis'}
          19         {'SubChassis'}
          20         {'Bus Expansion Chassis'}
          21         {'Peripheral Chassis'}
          22         {'Storage Chassis'}
          23         {'Rack Mount Chassis'}
          24         {'Sealed-Case PC'}
          default    {"$value"}
        }

      }
      $result
    }
  }

  return (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_SystemEnclosure | Select-Object -Property $ChassisTypes).ChassisType

}

Get-ChassisType

# When using a desktop.
# >PS ((Get-ChassisType) -eq "Desktop")
# >PS True

# When using a desktop.
# >PS Get-ChassisType
# >PS Desktop

# When using a laptop.
# >PS Get-ChassisType
# >PS Laptop
```