# Ifelse statement not working. Always defaults to the same condition

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I've done these so many times, but for some reason it seems to be only using the first condition and ignoring the rest.

Code:

```
$input = set-content -path ".\module.txt" -value 'Colors'
$output = get-content -path ".\module.txt"
    
    if ($output -ne ''){
        if ($output = 'Words'){set-content -path ".\module.txt" -value 'Numbers'}
            elseif ($output = 'Colors'){set-content -path ".\module.txt" -value 'Sounds'}
                else{write-host 'Somethings missing'}
                    }
```

No matter what I put in the **$input** variable, it will always complete the **first if statement** and change the text file content to read **Numbers**

So it can definitely update the content in the file, but it ignores the **elseif** and even the **else** statements.

Can anyone spot what I've done wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Win10 Powershell - Simple If/Elseif Depends on Condition Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51524013/win10-powershell-simple-if-elseif-depends-on-condition-order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For petes sake! I thought of something the second I posted this.

The equal sign (=) needs to be an equal switch (-eq)

```
$input = set-content -path ".\module.txt" -value 'Words'
$output = get-content -path ".\module.txt"
    
    if ($output -ne ''){
        if ($output -eq 'Words'){set-content -path ".\module.txt" -value 'Numbers'}
            elseif ($output -eq 'Colors'){set-content -path ".\module.txt" -value 'Sounds'}
                else{write-host 'Somethings missing'}
                    }
```

It works now.